# Create an App within an App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am being presented with a very interesting project. The task that I must complete is to figure out a way to allow a partner to be involved in an app without giving up their source code. The code will be included in the main bundle of the app so it is not dynamically stored. The partner has a fully functional app that is needed to be ran in a window within the main app at the appropriate time. I know having the partners create a web app would be ideal so it is treated like a webpage but I am more concerned with codes that must be written natively in iOS.

My question is what is the best way to go about solving this? In theory it is like an App within an App. Is there a way if they gave up their .app file I can include this in the bundle and then run it when I catch a certain event? Should I have the partners create their code in a framework and then import into the shell project? What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way if they gave up their .app file I can include this in
>   the bundle and then run it when I catch a certain event?

No, you'll want to have them create a library instead. You can then include that library in your project.

Creating a library is as simple as:

1. Choose File->New...->Project... in Xcode.
2. Select the "Cocoa Touch Static Library" project template.
3. Add your code.
4. Build.

The result is a static library that you can add to your application(s). The library will contain the compiled code that you added, but doesn't include the source code. The library developer should provide whatever header files are necessary to use the code in the library.

Comment: Yes exactly you can do this as the way @Caleb describes.

Answer (score 2):

If your 2nd-party doesn't want to provide you with the source code, why doesn't he compile it to object code then let you simply link it to your app?

By the way, at least on official (non-jailbroken) iDevices, apps can't 'embed' or 'open' one another in such a way - you can open an app programmatically if 1. it's a separate app 2. it has a registered special URL associated to its bundle.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials and or examples of compiling code into object code? I might not be understanding correctly.

Comment: @Krzemienski any compiler has an option for that. Have a look at 'clang -c'. (And of course google object code.)

Answer (score 0):

An App within an App is possible however it requires a common data framework that allows one app to reference the same data without confusing the the source of and destination of the data. 
Such a framework allows one app to interact with another app referencing the same data.